# simple moving average in python

Tags: python, moving-average

I am new to python. May I ask, for example the following codes, how do I know there is an attribute of mean function following the rolling function? (I am not sure if I said this correctly syntaxically) Thank you guys.

```
data['SMA50'] = data['SP500'].rolling(50).mean()
```

Comment: What is `data`? How is it initialized?

Comment: We'll need some more context to understand what your data is

Comment: This is a matter of documentation; you read about what `rolling` returns, to see if that value has a `mean` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, data is a DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `data` is a pandas data frame. To find the methods available, I first look at the documentation for [`rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

> Returns:  a Window or Rolling sub-classed for the particular operation

In the left-hand menu, I see a link for [Window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html). Clicking on this link shows all the available methods for `Rolling`.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask is there a command to let me to fully understand the meaning of "rolling" or any other methods when I am using jypter notebook? instead of checking the meaning online?

Comment: @TszChunLeung Python has a `help()` function. For example, you can do `help(data['SP500'].rolling)`. Personally, I prefer googling and reading the documentation in my browser.

Comment: Thank you very much